# VS2010 Extension for msdn and stackoverflow

Tags: visual-studio-2010, add-in

Is any one aware of an extension for visual studio that will show msdn help or any related stackoverflow post for a function right in the IDE. So that we don't have to google it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Create a macro like so

```
   Sub SearchSelectionOnStackOverflow()
        DTE.ItemOperations.Navigate("http://www.stackoverflow.com/search?q=" & DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.Text)
    End Sub
```

**ItemOperations.Navigate** will browse to an URL. Basically the macro will take the **current selection** in the active document and search for it on stackoverflow and show the results embedded in Visual Studio.

[Edit and Programmatically Create Macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k91y6132.aspx) talks about creating and editing macros. For convenience you can assign a **keyboard shortcut**

Comment: But there is no extension for it?

Comment: For stackoverflow I am not aware of none... for msdn ... if you install msdn along with Visual Studio a simple `F1` key after selecting a text will bring up help